# Expo Linking not redirect to specific path when app is not opening

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, deep-linking

Simply speaking, I have three containers, App.js, Homepage.js, Detail.js

App.js

```
let Home = createStackNavigator({
  HomePage: { screen: HomePage },
  Detail: { screen: DetailPage, path: 'detail' },
});

const RootPage = createAppContainer(createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  },
  xxx: {...}
}));

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Root>
        <RootPage />
      </Root>
    );
}
```

Homepage.js

```
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
export default class HomePage extends React.Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
    Linking.getInitialURL().then(this.urlRedirect);

    Linking.addEventListener('url', event => {
        this.urlRedirect(event.url);
    });
  }
  urlRedirect(url) {
      if(!url) return;
      let { path, queryParams } = Linking.parse(url);
      console.log(`Linked to app with path: ${path} and data: ${JSON.stringify(queryParams)}`);
      if (path != null)
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail", {
          item: {type: queryParams.type, data: {id: queryParams.id}}
        })
  }
  ...
}
```

if the app is in background, the link *{perfix}/--/detail?type=A&id=1* can redirect to detail page. however, the problem is if the app is not run in background, the above link can only redirect to the homepage. Please provide some advises, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I solve it by adding a line of code to constructor in Homepage.js

```
this.urlRedirect = this.urlRedirect.bind(this);
```